# How to create a file with headers and different variables in Octave?

Tags: csv, file, printf, octave

I need to create a file with some variables and their corresponding headings. For this I created an array with the variables making them the same size. To save or create this file I have tried many things but they do not work properly. I tried first `save blbl.txt V1 V2`, but I did not find the way to put headers. So I changed to `fprintf` as I found in a Matlab forum (I didn't find an example like this in the Octave forums), however it does something different than in the examples shown.

```
V1 = [1 2 3];
V2 = [4 5 6];
V = [V1.' , V2.'];
fileID=fopen('Pin.txt','w');
fprintf(fileID,'%12s %13s\n','V1','V2');
fprintf(fileID,'%6.6f %13.6f\n',V);
fclose(fileID);
```

It prints the headers and the two columns but it prints first the values of `V1` then the values in `V2`. I mean:

```
V1 V2
1   2
3   4 
5   6
```

and it should be (this is what supposedly happens in Matlab)

```
V1 V2
1   4
2   5
3   6
```

Does anyone understand why this is happening? Or if there is a better way to do this in Octave?

Comment: How did you build `V` to have it size 3x2? `V = [V1', V2']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual in Matlab/Octave, `fprintf` takes the values in [column-major order](https://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/what-are-column-major-and-row-major-representation-1.html). So you need to transpose `V`:

```
fprintf(fileID, '%6.6f %13.6f\n', V.');
```

or

```
fprintf(fileID, '%6.6f %13.6f\n', [V1; V2]);
```

Comment: Hello, yes I tried the transpose and now is correct. Thank you. I just wanted to know why it was happening that, as I couldn't understand how in the editor was correct but the printing no. Thanks for the column-mayor order information.

Comment: @DinaF Glad I could help. Knowing that Matlab/Octave is column-major is very useful, for example when you use [linear indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html)

Answer (score 0):

What are you *trying* to do? It seems to me you are simply trying to create a csv file (well, with spaces instead of commas).

If that's the case, you could use csv-related functions. E.g.

```
pkg load io
C = vertcat( { 'V1', 'V2' }, num2cell( V ) );
cell2csv ( 'Pin.txt', C, ' ' );
```

In any case, the reason the output comes out in that way, as Luis also hinted, is the following (taken from the Matlab documentation)

> If your function call provides more input arguments than there are formatting operators in the format specifier, then the operators are reused.

Since matlab and octave column-major-order (i.e. the next element is the one 'below', not the one 'to the right'), if you want to 'reuse' variables in this manner,  you need to arrange things as Luis suggested.

*If matlab produces the 'correct' result instead, then this is actually a matlab bug, since it should be doing it the same as octave in this case, and you shouldn't rely on it*.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this other option I tried it and work pretty well.